# Having trouble starting with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm reluctant to even ask this because it feels so remedial, but I've been scouring through tutorials and docs all morning with no results.

I'm trying to get up and running using AngularJS out of interest and can't seem to get the darn thing to work for me. I have local copies of jquery and angular which I know are being referenced correctly because I'm seeing my jquery bit in index.html working properly.

Please forgive any mis-nomers in my explanation:
I'm trying to create a simple ng-app with one controller to grab and output the value of the username input field. I'm under the impression that what I have *should work. Here's the code:

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="indexApp">
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src ="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jqscripts.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/indexApp.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-controller="HelloController">
  <h1>Hello Angular</h1>
  <p>your name: <input type="text" ng-model="username" name="username"></p>

  <p>{{ show() }}</p>
 </div> 

</body>
</html>
```

indexApp.js

```
var indexApp = angular.module("myapp", []);

indexApp.controller('HelloController', ['$scope', 
  function($scope) {
    $scope.username = 'Sam';
    $scope.show = function() {return $scope.username;};
});
```

I have the feeling this is something obvious I'm missing, but I'd love to at least get it up and running!

Comment: FYI, if you load jQuery AFTER AngularJS, Angular will use its own stripped down version called [jQLite](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) instead.  That said, while you learn, I recommend not using jQuery.  Then you'll learn how to do things in the "Angular Way" instead of relying on your jQuery skills.  There's nothing wrong with jQuery. After you become proficient in Angular, you may find reasons to use the two together, but you'll be making informed decisions about why you want to use it and where you should (in Directives) and shouldn't (in Controllers) use it.

Comment: Good to know jme11! Probably wouldn't have figured that out until I invested much more time trying to learn Angular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<html ng-app="indexApp">
```

This is your problem. You are supplying the name of the javascript variable which is different from the name of the module you actually registered with angular.module('name', dependencies).

When specifying ng-app in your HTML directive you need to use the name that you supplied as the first parameter. In this case`myapp`. The answer above will work but you could just as easily change your HTML to be

```
<html ng-app="myapp">
```

and everything will work properly.

Comment: Chose this as the best answer because of the explanation. Thanks a bunch! Definietly something that should have hit me square between the eyes...

Comment: @SamJohnson No problem :) Angular has a steep learning curve but it is well worth the investment!

Answer (score 3):

Here you are:

```
var indexApp = angular.module("indexApp", []);
```

Hope this help.